# path.resolve vs. relative path in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I often see examples in node like:

```js
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = path.resolve(__dirname, 'credentials.json')
```

I understand that `path` is a useful module when dealing with more complex situations, but in this case, why not just use

```js
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = './credentials.json'
```

?

Comment: It depends on how you use this variable. Relative path is relative to the working directory which might be changed by how you launch your node app or programmatically.

Comment: `process.chdir('/go/find/your/credentials/now')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_dirname):

> The directory name of the current module. This is the same as the path.dirname() of the __filename.

This means when using this:

```js
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = './credentials.json'
```

NodeJS will look for `credentials.json` in the current working directory

While when using this:

```js
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = path.resolve(__dirname, 'credentials.json')
```

NodeJS will look for `credentials.json` in the same directory where this module is

Lets say you have a directory structure like this:

```
/
+-- home
|   +-- USERNAME
|       +-- project
|           +-- index.js
|           +-- credentials.json
```

if you run the following commands (from the root directory `/`):

```
cd home/USERNAME/project
node index.js
```

The code will work just fine in both cases.

But if you run it like this

```
node home/USERNAME/project/index.js
```

With `path.resolve` you'll get: `home/USERNAME/project/credentials.json` which is correct

and without it you'll get: `./credentials.json`, which is wrong as your current directory is `/`.

Comment: Oh okey so in node, compared to frontend JS, it matters from where the script is executed? Because I'm used to thinking everything is relative to the file I am currently writing in.